# Need a way to perform auto confirm for firefox or any other browser popup's

Tags: browser

Is there a way to auto confirm popup.
For example i'm deleting file via firefox this operation triggers a confirmation popup when the options are ok and cancel.

In this case i need to click on ok button automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do this in C#:

Perform the desired action (like delete) and then:

```
    SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}"); //in case if the focus was on ok button


    SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}"); //in case if the focus was on cancel button
    SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
```