# Handle Certificate dialog window in Windows 7 with WatiN

Tags: watin

I've faced with a problem handling certificate dialog window in Windows 7 with WatiN. What dialog handler should I use? I've tried all available classes but still no results.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the dialog without watin help by using SendKeys method

See this post:

[Need a way to perform auto confirm for firefox or any other browser popup's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120259/need-a-way-to-perform-auto-confirm-for-firefox-or-any-other-browser-popups)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This works on local machine, but doesn't work on remote machine.

Comment: Yes, You need to run this when there is a logged in user. Because there is an interaction with the OS.